# How to load complete data into PFQueryTableViewController and implement objectDidLoad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquerytableviewcontrolle

I am trying to read data from parse cloud and present it in tableview according to customised cell. So far I have no problem with presenting this data. However I need to add some features to this tableview's cell such as

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

To add this feature I need to know when the table has been loaded completely. When table view loaded for first time only cells presented are passed in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. But I want to know when exactly theses cells has been changed. Another feature is passing an integer number from source VC to search in the cell and scroll to that specific cell. Something like:

```
    //Traverse into table
    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {

        NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    }
```

However I need to do it somewhere outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I found this:

```
(void)objectDidLoad:(NSError* error) {

    [super objectDidLoad:error];
    [self.queryInProgress cancel]; //query finished. self.queryInProgress = nil;

}
```

But I get this error:

[image]

There is no selector `objectDidLoad` in `PFQueryTableViewController`!

Here is the reference: [objectDidLoad](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQueryTableViewController.html#//api/name/objectsDidLoad:)

and it says:

you must call [super objectsDidLoad:] in your implementation.

What dose that mean? Appreciate if anyone can help me with this?

Comment: `objectsDidLoad` vs `objectDidLoad` there is an "s" difference.

Answer (score 1):

You miss a character "s" . 
This is :

```
- (void)objectsDidLoad:(PFUI_NULLABLE NSError *)error
```